# Autoprefixer vs LESS/Sass mixins?

Tags: css, sass, less

The [autoprefixer](http://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/) tool is a CSS post-processor that adds the correct vendor prefixes to otherwise 'naive' style declarations.

How does this compare (in terms of effectiveness and developer experience) to mixins provided by [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) for this same goal of generating vendor-specific styles?

Comment: Is there an actual programming problem here?

Comment: SO isn't just for problems. I'm asking a quantitative question about the difference in capabilities between two pieces of software.

Comment: You can use Autoprefixer with Sass/LESS. Autoprefixer for CSS 3 prefixer and Sass for business logic.

I create Autoprefixer exactly to use it with Sass, not to replace :).

Comment: I still don't see what is "primarily opinion-based" about this question. Feels like people could spend a lot more time answering questions and providing value than going around closing questions that people are interested in.

Comment: This is a great article on using Autoprefixer with Sass (specifically using Compass). It makes a great case for the use of Autoprefixer in lieu of sass mixins to manage vendor prefixing.

http://www.zell-weekeat.com/compass-vs-autoprefixer/

Answer (score 4):

LESS and Sass both have various frameworks and libraries you can integrate into your workflow, most of which include some kind of prefixing mixin, so you will very likely get the same results from either method, and if that's the only thing you use it for, then it probably won't matter which one you use.

Where LESS and Sass get their power is in all the other things they can do, including things like declaration nesting, variables, loops, and other mixins, which may or may not be what you need for a given project.

With this power, of course, comes differences in syntax - you start moving away from native CSS, including the syntax for handling prefixes. In LESS and Sass, if you want to have vendor prefixes on something, you generally go through the `@mixin` syntax. This is the main difference in "developer experience" that you're going to see, but again, LESS and Sass are larger tools than autoprefixer, so you're probably going to be taking the mixin syntax in part and parcel with the other syntax changes.

In other words - use tools like autoprefixer or prefixr if all you're using is the prefixing, and use LESS or Sass if you want to use the other features.

Comment: Autoprefixers and stuff like LESS and SASS do very different things. The former just adds prefixes for better cross browser compat, whilst the two latter ones are CSS _preprocessors_. As you say, you can add a mixin to prefix certain properties in LESS or SASS but that's not the same as passing pure CSS to a prefixer. Also, LESS and SASS don't have any frameworks or libraries at all, unless you mean they are those themselves

Comment: @Bojangles - Compass calls itself a framework, it could also be considered a "mixin library." Frameless and Bootstrap are also considered frameworks and/or libraries, both of which are available in LESS and Sass. That is what I'm referring to, of which both LESS and Sass have several. (See also: [library (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing) - a collection of implementations of a behavior)

Comment: You don't mention Compass in your answer. Bootstrap and Frameless are frameworks in themselves, of which LESS _is a part of_. LESS nor SASS are a "collection of implementations of behaviour" - they are _preprocessors_. Please get your terminology right

Comment: @Bojangles - I never said LESS or Sass *were* libraries, you did. I said they *had* libraries, in my very first sentence. Compass *is* a library - it's a collection of mixins, including several ones that handle vendor prefixing.